# Decrypting Hadoop Snappy File

Tags: python, hadoop, snappy

So I'm having some issues decrypting a snappy file from HDFS.  If I use `hadoop fs -text` I am able to uncompress and output the file just file.  However if I use `hadoop fs -copyToLocal` and try to uncompress the file with python-snappy I get

> snappy.UncompressError: Error while decompressing: invalid input

My python program is very simple and looks like this:

```
import snappy

with open (snappy_file, "r") as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()
    uncompressed = snappy.uncompress(data)
    print uncompressed
```

This fails miserably for me.  So I tried another text, I took the output from `hadoop fs -text` and compressed it using the **python-snappy** library.  I then outputted this to a file.  I was able to then read this file in and uncompress it just fine.

**AFAIK** snappy is backwards compatible between version.  My python code is using the latest snappy version and I'm guessing hadoop is using an older snappy version.  Could this be a problem?  Or is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay well I figured it out.  Turns out that what I was using was the raw mode decompress on a file that was compressed using hadoop's framing format.  Even when I tried the StreamDecompressor in 0.5.1 it still failed due to a framing error.  python-snappy 0.5.1 defaults to the new snappy [framing format](https://github.com/google/snappy/blob/master/framing_format.txt) and thus can't decompress the hadoop snappy files.

Turns out that the master version, 0.5.2, has added support for the hadoop framing format.  Once I built this and imported it I was able to decompress the file easily:

```
with open (snappy_file, "r") as input_file:
  data = input_file.read()
  decompressor = snappy.hadoop_snappy.StreamDecompressor()
  uncompressed = decompressor.decompress(data)
```

Now the only issue is that this isn't technically a pip version yet, so I guess I'll have to wait or just use the build from source.

Comment: Hi @anoneironaut,  I've got a question you might be able to answer! There is not much documentations about python-snappy steaming! I am trying to use python-snappy streaming to compress my files in  parallel. and I want to combine those streams into 1 stream snappy if possible. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: Sorry @Leila, my usage was fairly simple. Never tried something like that!

Comment: Hi @anoneironaut, I've followed your code but when I want to see the results with `print(uncompressed)` I get `b''`. Any idea?

Comment: @anoneironaut I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, same for me. Im getting b''. That looks like empty bytes.

Comment: Same issue here. I get empty bytes when I try to read directly from a .snappy file with this . Has anyone figured out another solution/library? Is it a bug in python-snappy's hadoop snappy module itself?

Comment: when I removed "hadoop_snappy" it did work instead of returning the empty bytes.
```with open("data.snappy", mode="rb") as input_file:
     contents = input_file.read()
decompressor = snappy.StreamDecompressor()
uncompressed = decompressor.decompress(contents)```