# How to read Spark log files? .Iz4 or .snappy

Tags: python, apache-spark, snappy, lz4

I want to read some logs but I cannot. So far, I've tried:

- `hadoop fs -text <file>`

But the only thing I get is:  `INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lz4]` (same for .snappy)

- `val rawRdd = spark.sparkContext.sequenceFile[BytesWritable, String](<file>)`

It returns me `<file> is not a SequenceFile`

- `val rawRdd = spark.read.textFile(<file>)`

In this case `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z`

- download the file to a local filesystem and then use `lz4 -d <file>` to decompress and try to see the content
- I followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48029807/5081366):

`with open (snappy_file, "r") as input_file:
  data = input_file.read()
  decompressor = snappy.hadoop_snappy.StreamDecompressor()
  uncompressed = decompressor.decompress(data)`

but when I want to `print(uncompressed)`, I only get `' 'b`

Comment: Did you find the answer?